# Using vectorization to compute moving average in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, moving-average

I wrote a script to compute simple moving average of a vector using for-loop:

```
X=rand(1000,1); 
Y=nan(size(A));
for i=100:length(A);
    Y(i)=mean(X(i-99:i));
end
```

Could I use any vectorization method to avoid the loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily avoid the loop by using either convolution ([`conv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html)) or [`smooth`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html) if you have the curve fitting toolbox.

```
filterSize = 5;
Y = conv(X, ones(1, filterSize) / filterSize, 'same');

% Or with the curve-fitting toolbox
Y = smooth(X, filterSize);
```